# Any way we can share a specific item publicly from a private S3 bucket?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, django-rest-framework

The question is pretty vague but here's the entire problem statement. I am using Django REST APIs, and I'm generating invocies for my clients. Using wkhtmltopdf, I'm able to generate a PDF file which gets automatically backed up to S3. Now, we need to retreive the said invoice once our client clicks on a link.

We're using pre-signed URLs right now, which last for 12 hours, right? Once that link expires, the entire backend fails.

I mean, even if we go for permanent pre-signed links, would there not be a security issue?
I could really use some guidance on this.

Comment: You say that "our client clicks on a link" -- what generates this link and how is it provided to your clients? For example, is it sent to them via email?

Answer (score 3):

> Now, we need to retreive the said invoice once our client clicks on a link.

> We're using pre-signed URLs right now [...]

Only generate the pre-signed URL for a given S3 URI when the authenticated client clicks on the link. You can then give it a very short expiry.

Comment: How do we ensure that we have an authenticated client clicking on the link? as in, are you suggesting a service like cognito?

Comment: No, I'm assuming your clients log in somehow before they "click on a link".